# Reading a file with 1024^3 data points

Tags: fortran77

I am trying to read a file with 1024^3 single precision data points. The code looks something like this

```
  real, allocatable :: stored_data(:)

  character(255):: in_file
  integer n
  integer*8 length, length4

  length = n*n*n            ! number of data points
  length4 = 4*length
  in_file = "filename.dat"

  allocate(stored_data(length))

  open(10,file=trim(in_file),access="direct",
 &     form="unformatted",recl=length4)
  read(10,rec=1) stored_data
  close(10)

  deallocate(stored_data)
```

But when I am running the code, I get the following error:

```
Fortran runtime error: RECL parameter is non-positive in OPEN statement
```

I guess its because of the large value of the variable "length4". 
Any workarounds?

Comment: no need to read all as one record, use a smaller recl and multiple reads.

Comment: Hmm. Just noticed I think n n n produces a 4-byte result (the calculation is not upcast because length is 8 byte.  Declare n 4 byte..

Comment: oops.. 1024^3 fits so you are ok on the second comment, but dangerously close - it breaks at n=1291..

Comment: That's not FORTRAN77, `allocate` was introduced in Fortran 90. In the code you show the variable `n` is nowhere initialised so any value which depends on the value of `n`, as `length4` does, is unpredictable. Please don't tell us that you have omitted the initialisation from the post.